# findstr syntax in Batch

Tags: batch-file, syntax, findstr

I got my code for cmd:

```
dir | findstr /b %date% | findstr / Neues > C:/users/user/desktop/file.txt
```

works perfectly for me and write this in the txt:

DD.MM.YYYY .. HH.MM .... XXXX  Neues Textdokument.txt

Now I need to run this every day at the same time, so I want to put it as a batch into the time scheduler.
I'm a beginner in batch, but I have this (it don't work):

```
cd "directory"
dir ^| findstr /b /m %date% "Neues" > C:/users/user/desktop/file.txt
```

I can't find the mistake, can you?

Comment: At a guess, `dir *Neues*| findstr /b "%date%" > C:\users\user\desktop\file.txt` to find all filenames containing "Neues" which have a datestamp of "%date%"

Comment: …or, _if you don't want to be reliant on a specific date format, or layout from the `dir` command_: `@forfiles /p "directory" /d 0 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @fdate0x09@ftime0x09@fsize0x09@file">"C:\users\user\desktop\file.txt"` Open a Command Prompt window and type `forfiles /?` for further information on its usage, and options. BTW, you main error in your posted code, is that you're under the misunderstanding that you need to escape the vertical bar, _(pipe)_, in a batch file, just remove that caret, _(`^`)_.

Comment: @Magoo
This work for me! 
I just added a "^" in front of the pipe because its for the batch :)
Thanks!